# Scheme Binary To Decimal

Tags: binary, type-conversion, scheme, decimal

I am trying to find a way to convert binary to decimal using Scheme.

```
(binaryToDecimal b)
```

A function that takes a binary number and returns its decimal value. (binaryToDecimal 1101) returns 13.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheme Binary List to Decimal Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59114001/scheme-binary-list-to-decimal-sum)

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far, so we can help you. Don't forget to add sample input and expected output.

Comment: 1101 is not a binary number and definitely not thirteen; it's one thousand, one hundred and one.