# Scheme Binary List to Decimal Sum

Tags: list, binary, scheme, decimal, converters

A function that takes a list of binary numbers and returns their decimal sum.

```
Call: (addBinary '(1101 111 10 101))

(define (addBinary binaryList))

returns 27
```

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far, so we can help you. Also make sure that what you post is valid code that compiles, not like the code you posted. Don't forget to add sample input and expected output.

Comment: Your code is invalid since you need at least one expression after the lambda list. also `'(1101 111 10 101)` are not binary `'(#b1101 #b111 #b10 #b101)` is. `(+ #b1101 #b111 #b10 #b101) ; ==> 27` when you evaluate it. An integer doesn't really have a base, but its visualization does.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Racket and Guile:

```lisp
(define (addBinary binaryList)
  (foldl ; or fold, depending on dialect
   (lambda (n r)
     (+ r (string->number (number->string n) 2)))
   0 binaryList))
```